# Nginx url Rewrite (help)

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Anyone tell me how to rewrite URL in Nginx

```
https://dl.expamledomain.com/download.php?p=524&st=mmmnGreUwmpRTGl7RO9NtGLhgQZrQ1IW&fn=file.zip
```

to

```
https://dl.expamledomain.com/dwn/524/mmmnGreUwmpRTGl7RO9NtGLhgQZrQ1IW/file.zip
```

second our download.php file in the root public_html folder.

I have used this rule on .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^dl/(\w+)/(\w+)/(.*)/?$ download.php?pt=$1&tk=$2&flen=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

its working fine but I try many on Nginx rule like this

I try this code in Nginx but not working

```
    http{

       server {
          listen       80;
          server_name  *.oursitename.com;

   location / {
    rewrite ^(?i)/dl/(\w+)/(\w+)/(.*)/?$ /download.php?pt=$1&tk=$2&flen=$3 last;
 }

  location = /download.php {
    # Your fastcgi_pass configuration
}
    }
```

its show me this error

```
" open() "/home/username/public_html/dl/515/25xfkUNYOGvvOt0z7ko9YkpHCWZrlRfX/file72.exe" failed (2: No such file or directory),"
```

our file location like this

```
1.Home
    1.Username
     1.public_html
       1.downloadfolder
       2.download.php
       3.index.php
       4.htaccess
```

Comment: If the client asks for the first one, you want to send a `HTTP` redirect to the second one? Or rather you want to rewrite the second one into the first one?

Comment: i want rewrite first url to second url

Comment: This is not very good approach, please see my comment for the answer by @PiotrP.Karwasz. This kind of things need sanitisation, validation steps, to verify the request for specific characters. usually in a real programming language and not conf files at the server level.

Comment: The example Apache configuration is inconsistent with your question:1. it rewrites the second URL into the first one, 2. it rewrites the URI Path `/dl/...` not `/dwn/...` as in your example. I deleted my answer to which @JonnieJS is referring, since it is inconsistent with what you are really asking.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz ok so what is the solution what is rewrite rule of above htaccess rule

Comment: The error you are getting, means that control does not reach the `location /` block. If you have multiple `server` blocks, it might reach another virtual host (according to the URL and `server_name`). Increasing the log level to debug (cf. [error_log directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log)) allows you to pick into the `location` selection, while `rewrite_log on;` logs the rewritten URLs at a `notice` level.

Answer (score 0):

**NGINX** rewrite rules always use absolute URI Paths, so in order to rewrite your **second** URL into the **first** one (which is what the provided Apache2 rule does), you just need to add a couple of `/`:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^(?i)/dl/(\w+)/(\w+)/(.*)/?$ /download.php?pt=$1&tk=$2&flen=$3 last;
}
location = /download.php {
    # Your fastcgi_pass configuration
}
```

The [NC flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc) is translated into the PCRE mode modifier `(?i)` (cf. [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/498855/530633)), while the [QSA flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) is the default **NGINX** behaviour.

**Remark**: Under Apache2 it is also better to put your rewrite rules in the server config, instead of `.htaccess` files and disable them altogether: you gain in performance and they will not be published on the Web if you make a configuration mistake.

Comment: not working show me 404 error page

Comment: A `/` was missing in `location = /download.php`. Of course you can use a more general location for all PHP files: `location ~ \.php$`, which you probably already have. The NGINX's error log (`/var/log/nginx/error.log`) will tell you whether the PHP file was executed or not.

Comment: Thanks for help what is # Your fastcgi_pass configuration . how to find it from our centos server

Comment: It is a comment line, it stands for all the directives needed to pass the request to the **PHP-FPM** server, i.e. a set of params [like this](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) (usually in a separate file) and a [fastcgi_pass](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_pass) directive.

Comment: show me error in error file " open() "/home/username/public_html/dl/515/25xfkUNYOGvvOt0z7ko9YkpHCWZrlRfX/file72.exe" failed (2: No such file or directory),"

Comment: I updated our main post please check it we face the error . and our main post I also show our file hierarchy